# discord.py get member instance from name#discriminator

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have a string with the name of an user `user = 'somename#1111'` how can I mention him? (I get the name from google sheets that's why it's a string)

I tried with:

```
@client.command()
async def mention(ctx):
    user : discord.Member = 'somename#1111'
    await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} hello!")
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Also, did you manage to get the message edit command working as you wanted?

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this method is valid, I'd recommend switching to saving user IDs instead of usernames + discriminators, as user IDs are constant, but users are able to change their names and discriminators.

```py
@client.command()
async def mention(ctx):
    user = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, name="somename", discriminator="1111")
    await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} hello!")
```

And with the ID:

```py
@client.command()
async def mention(ctx):
    user = ctx.guild.get_member(112233445566778899) # replace user ID there
    try:
        await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} hello!")
    except:
        await ctx.send("Sorry, that user has left the server!")
```

---

**References:**

- [`utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)
- [`User.discriminator`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.User.discriminator)
- [`Guild.get_member()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member)
- [`Guild.get_member_named()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member_named) - "Returns the first member found that matches the name provided."

Comment: You can also use `f'<@{user.id}>'` which is the raw format for mentions

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used user.mention, but what I do is I get the user's id, then mention them like this:

```py
await ctx.send(f'<@!{user.id}> hello!')
```