# How do I check if a user is in a server while only having the bot's guilds [python discord bot]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So I finally managed to almost get my discord bot working. The problem is, while only having the bot's guilds (`bot.guilds`), I am too stupid to access the members of it. Here is some pseudo-code: (I'm using datetime, asyncio and other functions in the actual bot)

```
def check_for_bds():
    any_bds = True # done by a function 
    bd_list = ["member1#1234", "member2#1234"] # a list of the members who have their birthday
    if any_bds:
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            for member in bd_list:
                if member in guild.members: # this doesn't work as guild.members isn't accessable like this
                    await guild.system_channel.send(f"@{member} has their birthday today! Happy Birthday! ")
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What do you mean by "I am too stupid to access the members of it"?

Comment: Well, I mean I cannot check if the user is in the server of not... I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: Because `guild.members` is a list of `discord.Member` instances and `member` is a string, I'll write an answer

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah, I didn't know how to call that thing with discord.Member instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Guild.members` return a list of `discord.Member` instances and you're comparing a string to it. You should get a member instance and then compare it.

```py
for guild in bot.guilds:
    for member in bd_list:
        name, discriminator = member.split("#") # getting the name and discriminator
        member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, name=name, discriminator=discriminator) # Getting the instance
        if member in guild.members:
            await guild.system_channel.send(f"@{member} has their birthday today! Happy Birthday! ")
```

Also `@{member}` will not work, a member mention internally looks like this `<@!{member_id}>`, fortunatelly a `discord.Member` instance already has the `mention` attribute

```py
await guild.system_channel.send(f"{member.mention} has their birthday today! Happy Birthday! ")
```

#### References:

- [`Guild.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members)
- [discord.py get member instance from name#discriminator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62161699/discord-py-get-member-instance-from-namediscriminator)
- [`utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)
- [`Member.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.mention)