# How to convert a string to a member for python bots?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am having trouble converting a string into a member class for discord.py. My goal is to have the python bot I am writing to be able to save a set of users in the form of a string and write it to a text file (which I've managed). Subsequently, I would like to recall those strings and reference them as an id so my bot can private message a user. Most of the code I found works as it should when appropriately called in discord itself, but **I want to be able to call the command itself from the script for the bot.**

I.e., the following works as intended

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, member : commands.MemberConverter):
    await member.send(member, 'Message')

#called with something like .dm user#1234 on Discord itself
```

but I want my bot to be able to do something like

```
file = ['user#1234', 'user#2345', ...]
member = file[1:]
await member.send(member, 'Message')

#Where a string can be passed into an argument to reference a user or how to convert the
#string into a member class and then called to privately DM someone all in the bot code.
```

I kinda decided to write this bot on a whim yesterday morning and I have no prior knowledge in creating a bot. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py get member instance from name#discriminator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62161699/discord-py-get-member-instance-from-namediscriminator)

Comment: It's close, but I wanted it so I didn't have to call a client side command to get an ID of someone (from my understanding of what ctx does). itzFlubby's response helps more as I didn't understand the syntax of private DM commands. Now I just need to reference the database into messaging each of the individuals directly. Basically, I've written a web scraper to collect some numbers off it, and I want "when int x changes", "message all people in database" and not so much of, User queries then Bot replies. At least, that's what my limited understanding is telling me from that question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a member by name with the [utility functions found in the API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#utility-functions)

```
member = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, name='Foo')
```

Afterwards you can check, if no dm with this user exists. Otherwise create one and always send the message.

```
for element in file[1:]:
    info = element.split("#")
    member = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, name=info[0], discriminator=info[1])
    if member.dm_channel is None:
        await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send("Message")
```

Comment: The member.dm_channel.send definitely helps as I don't exactly understand the syntax of discord.py yet. The biggest thing now is that I don't understand message.guild.members as it is registering as undefined in my code. My approach is unorthodox so my main question is still, is there any way to limit other routines so I just need the str var converted into a member. I don't plan on having that many user ids in the text file I open so I'll just verify it physically. That, or I just write member.dm_channel.send("Message") statements. I guess this question is about dm_channel.send syntax really.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, you're using ext.commands
Use `ctx.guild` instead of `message.guild` I'll update this in my answer

Comment: I haven't completely verified whether your solution works but I'll probably be just one of those terrible coders that just uses multiple statements instead of a for loop. Also, this is the first time I've installed discord.py, requests, and BS4 so I only skimmed through the API cuz I don't understand like 80% of it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can look through [these docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html) to understand the synatx of the discord.py API-Wrapper. You won't need to know everything in there. Don't feel bad about yourself, we're all here to lear ;) Feel free to ask more questions on stackoverflow! There will always be people who are ready to help ;)