# Discord bot get user id by only name

Tags: discord, discord.py

So I'm currently making a bot that should dm users who entered their discord name(example#0000) outside of discord, I now need the bot to convert their names into their Id's, in order to dm them.

Is that even possible?
For clarification, the bot is not on the same server as the users and has never interacted with them.

Comment: This question has been asked too many times. You can try to browse through other questions. And please close your question if you find an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py get member instance from name#discriminator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62161699/discord-py-get-member-instance-from-namediscriminator)

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński This solution requires the bot to be on the same server as the targets or am I wrong?

Comment: The bot has to share a server with them in order to send them a message.

Comment: Yes, of course. I don’t think it’s possible to get the user/member instance by name if you don’t share a guild, I know that you can fetch it using an ID, but it’s not possible by name

Answer (score 0):

No, it’s not possible to get a `User`/`Member` instance by name if you don’t share a guild, the only possible way would be to fetch it from the API using an ID

```
user = await bot.fetch_user(123345567901)
```